# Exponentially decaying rank accourding to datetime in c#

Tags: c#, real-time, ranking

I am looking for helpon how to give an exponentially decaying weight according to time. I am writing a small web searching program in c# and want to rank search results according to a time decaying factor. 
Can anybody help, i am a newbie to ranking algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Subtract your time values from your reference time (in a real time environment that would be `DateTime.Now`) to give you a `Timespan`.
2) Using this `Timespan`, use one of the Total methods (i.e. `TotalHours`) to get a double value.
3) If you want to do exponentially decaying weights, then try looking at this:

[Exponential Moving Averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)

Answer (score 0):

Exponential is called exponential because of the properties of a mathematical exponent.  Take the age of the result and do the following:

rankAdjustment = age ^ age;

That will give you an adjustment to your rank that exponentially changes with length of time.